# Is there a negative form for adverbs?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs, negation

So if you want to say you walk quickly you say 早く歩く. Great.

Now, suppose you want to say you walk *un*quickly. Could you potentially say something like 早くなく歩く?

The obvious answer is you simply say you walk slowly, but someone I tutor asked me what the negative form of an adverb is and I was caught of guard. I've looked around and didn't find anything so I assume it's just not a concept in Japanese but I wanted to make sure I gave them the correct information.

Comment: "早くなく" is probably grammatically correct, but feels somewhat uncanny. On the other hand, so does "unquickly"... Maybe "早くないように"?

Comment: What about 早くないで歩く?

Comment: Usually we just negate the predicate: 早く歩かない.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed, in this case, we rarely say 早くなく歩く but ゆっくり歩く. I think we usually don't use the negative form of an adverb but an adverb that has a opposite meaning. Though a few people may say this way.